# Using variable and return value of assignment in printf

Tags: c, printf

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a = 9;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n",a,  (a=10), a);

    return 0;
}
```

prints the following output along with the warning

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:31: warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined
   printf("%d, %d, %d\n",a,  (a=10), a);
                               ^
main.c:8:31: warning: operation on ‘a’ may be undefined

9
10, 10, 10
```

Now, I understand that return value of assigning one variable to some value is the value that has been assigned to([Low level details of C/C++ assignment operator implementation. What does it return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697643/low-level-details-of-c-c-assignment-operator-implementation-what-does-it-retu#:~:text=The%20assignment%20operator%20is%20defined,the%20expression%20has%20been%20evaluated).). But interestingly, printing variable 'a' even before assignment is printing 10 instead of 9. Why is it so? It looks like assignment of a is being completed and then all other value is printed. But is it compiler dependent behavior or specified in C, which I didn't find any reference for.

Comment: The order of evaluation of arguments is undefined in C. Looking for a suitable duplicate... [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397995/10871073) may help.

Comment: There's no order to the evaluation of arguments. Those `a` could all be 9, they could all be 10, or it could be some mix of the two. This could change depending on your level of optimization, platform, etc.

Comment: okay, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior, i found the duplicate here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/10871073

Comment: Relevant: [Order of evaluation of arguments in function calling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616986/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-in-function-calling)