Regarding behavior of printf() function
Why does behavior of a printf() function, or possibly of the pre-increment/decrement operator vary when a specific parameter is passed to (in my case) a different printf() function?
Warning : Rookie behavior and thinking ahead
I learnt that functions parameters are passed from right to left, so I was playing around with that idea, and that was when I wrote this code :
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int a = 0;
    
    printf("%d, %d, %d", a, a++, ++a);
    
    return 0;
} 

Which gave me an output of :
2, 1, 2
Which was surprising, but then I learnt that the pre-increment value is not assigned until after all parameters are passed (this is my rough understanding, please provide a better explanation!). I understood that post-increment is instantly assigned.
But then, I got curious when a friend gave a different explanation, and trying to prove her wrong, I wrote this piece of code :
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *a){
    *a = 300;
    return 0;
}

int main(void){

    int a = 0;
    
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n\n", a, a++, ++a, func(&a), a, a++, ++a);

    return 0;
} 

Which then gave me an output of :
302, 301, 301, 0, 2, 1, 1
Which ended up putting both our explanations into doubt.
So, the question arises : Is the 'fact' of pre-increment not being instantly assigned subject to the compiler's whims?
And as a bonus, this next piece of code gave me even more doubts :
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int *a){
    *a = 300;
    return 0;
}

int main(void){

    int a = 0;
    
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, a++, ++a);
    
    a = 0;
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n\n", a, a++, ++a, func(&a), a, a++, ++a);

    return 0;
} 

Which gave me an output of
2, 1, 1
302, 301, 301, 0, 2, 1, 1

The second printf() had somehow influenced the first.
The question is, why, and how?
(I'm using GCC)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616986/order-of-evaluation-of-arguments-in-function-calling is a closer dupe in my opinion.
